# Alternatives for MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, macos

What are the alternatives for MySQL Workbench on MacOS?

Because in the MacOS version of Workbench, you cannot forward engineer with the 'insert' queries unlike its windows version.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: What features do you need? What is your price limit when it comes to paid software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check out the following page where you will find promissing alternatives.
https://alternativeto.net/software/mysql-workbench/?platform=mac

Here you can already filter for license free/commercial/OpenSource

I can personally recommand DBeaver